# Confuse with Count usage in this code.

Tags: java, variables, count

I have a problem knowing what a part of this code works.

Here it is:

```
public class fia1 {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
   Band b0 = new Band();
   b0.name = "Beastie";
   b0.age = 25;
   Band b1 = new Band();
   b1.name = "Orchestra";
   b1.age = 100;
   System.out.println(b0.count);

   Band b2 = new Band();
   b2.name = "Polka";
   b2.age = 5;

   System.out.println("Names: " + b0.name + " " + b1.name + "
   " + b2.name);
   System.out.println(Band.count);
   b1 = b2;
   b1.age = 10;
   b0.age = b2.age + b0.age;

   System.out.println("Ages = " + b0.age + " " + b1.age + " "
   + b2.age);
    }
      }

  class Band {
   String name;
   int age;
   static int count = 1;
   Band() {
   count = count * 2;
   }
     }
```

So what this print is:

```
4
Names: Beastie, Orchestra, Polka
8
Ages: 35, 10, 10
```

I am confused as to how I get a 4 from my first count. Also I know that

```
 static int count = 1;
```

is where I am misunderstanding. Is this how java counts the variables? by 1, then 2 is Beastie, 3 is Orchestra and 4 is Polka? I really don't know how this is working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are multiplying count by 2 in the constructor and by the time you print out count, you have made two constructor calls.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `static` variable in `static int count = 1;`, which means every time you create a new `Band` the variable will be doubled for all `Bands` (since `count = count * 2;`)

See code below with comments that explains what happens:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Band b0 = new Band(); //Count becomes 1*2 = 2.
    b0.name = "Beastie";
    b0.age = 25;

    Band b1 = new Band(); //Count becomes 2*2 = 4.
    b1.name = "Orchestra";
    b1.age = 100;
    System.out.println(b0.count); //Prints 4.

    Band b2 = new Band(); //Count becomes 4*2 = 8.
    b2.name = "Polka";
    b2.age = 5;

    System.out.println("Names: " + b0.name + " " + b1.name + " " + b2.name);
    System.out.println(Band.count); //Prints 8.
    b1 = b2;
    b1.age = 10;
    b0.age = b2.age + b0.age;

    System.out.println("Ages = " + b0.age + " " + b1.age + " " + b2.age);
}
```

Comment: Ah! nice. Thanks dat! Now I get it. So another quick question, what is this part called?             " class Band {
                             String name;
                            int age;
                            static int count = 1;
                            Band() {
                           count = count * 2;
                     }
     }  "     a constructor?

Comment: Everything within the `class Band { ... }` section is the class, whereas everything within the `Band() { ... }` section is the constructor of the Band class.

Answer (score 1):

the `count` field in your `Band` class is a static field or class variable, meaning that all object of the `Band` class share it. Each time the constructor is called, `count` is updated. If you want to learn more about class variables, you can check out this [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable `count` is static, as it's declared as a `static int count = 1;`, each new construction of the class will perform any actions on `count` to all objects that have count. Anotherwords, when you call `b1`, the `count = count * 2;` command affects all instances of count, so the count variable in `b0` is also doubled as well.

Hence, when you first construct `band()` with `b0`, it takes `count` and sets it equal to 1 * 2 = 2. The second instance of `band()` with `b1` causes all instances of count to be equal to itself * 2. So, the count in `b1` is equal to 1*2 = 2, and the count in `b0` is equal to 2*2 = 4.